# how I can remove/handle this exception "java com.mchange.v2.c3p0.codegen.BeangenDataSourceGenerator <infile.xml> <OutputFile.java>"

Tags: java, mysql, xml

when I try to run ConnectionPOOL.java code for Mysql  I am getting this error

java com.mchange.v2.c3p0.codegen.BeangenDataSourceGenerator 
"infile.xml  OutputFile.java"

public class MysqlPool {

private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

private static volatile MysqlPool instance;

private MysqlPool(){

cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();

try {

cpds.setDriverClass(MysqlConnect.DRIVER); //loads the jdbc driver

cpds.setJdbcUrl(MysqlConnect.URL + MysqlConnect.DB_NAME);

cpds.setUser(MysqlConnect.USER_NAME);

cpds.setPassword(MysqlConnect.PASSWORD);

cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);

cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);

cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);

```
        }
```

catch (PropertyVetoException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}
}

public static MysqlConnect getConnection() throws SQLException {

```
MysqlPool localInstance = instance;

if (localInstance == null) {

synchronized (MysqlPool.class) {

localInstance = instance;


 if (localInstance == null) {

  instance = localInstance = new MysqlPool();

                }
            }
        }
 return new MysqlConnect(localInstance.cpds.getConnection());
    }


}
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's a Java cli command. Show us what you've done. Where's youre code? What's the exact error incl. stacktrace?

Comment: I have written that code for connection Pool in mysql